# Is it possible to display some minimum text on android phone screen when phone is asleep?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

Is it possible to display some minimum text on android phone screen when phone is asleep programmatically?

Is there a power efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is called DayDream mode. Clock, Photos, Quotes etc. can be displayed. Though it seems, DayDream mode should be installed & enabled. I found a tutorial which makes a interactive screen saver.

Please refer-http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-an-interactive-screen-saver-with-daydream--mobile-16604

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,your question is too vague.
And to answer your question :

Yes its possible to wake the phone from sleep mode using a service.